# Python datetime formatted string conversion-24 hour time issue

Tags: python, datetime

I have a need to convert a particular formatted string to another.

```
Source:
2018-08-10 9:00 PM - 9:40 PM

Target:
2018-08-10 21:00:00
```

I wrote the following:

```
def startofappt(strv):
    return strv.split(' - ')[0]

def convCalDate(dts, tms):
#     2018-08-08 5:50 PM
    from datetime import datetime, date, time
    dt = datetime.strptime(str(dts) + ' ' + str(startofappt(tms)), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p")
    return str(dt)

import datetime
datetoday = datetime.date.today()
from datetime import datetime, date, time
appointments_set = appointment.objects.filter(docid=11)
for appt in appointments_set:
    if appt.date > datetoday:
        print("Upcoming: ", appt.date, appt.time, convCalDate(appt.date, appt.time))
    else:
        print("Other:",appt.date, appt.time, convCalDate(appt.date, appt.time ))
```

Unfortunately I'm having trouble with 24 hour time.

Output:

```
Upcoming:  2018-08-10 9:00 PM - 9:40 PM 2018-08-10 09:00:00
Other: 2018-08-07 9:40 PM - 10:20 PM 2018-08-07 09:40:00
Other: 2018-08-07 9:00 PM - 9:40 PM 2018-08-07 09:00:00
Upcoming:  2018-08-08 5:50 PM - 6:10 PM 2018-08-08 05:50:00
Upcoming:  2018-08-08 6:10 PM - 6:30 PM 2018-08-08 06:10:00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Make it easy for us: hard-code `appointments_set` as the list you expect from `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try  reading your date time  as 12-hr format date-time and while returning the date return it as

```
def convCalDate(dts, tms):
    from datetime import datetime, date, time
    dt = datetime.strptime(str(dts) + ' ' + str(startofappt(tms)), "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
    return str(dt)

print convCalDate("2018-08-10", "9:00 PM - 9:40 PM") #returns 2018-08-10 21:00:00

print convCalDate("2018-08-10", "9:00 AM - 9:40 PM") #returns 2018-08-10 09:00:00
```

Hope it helps